# Concurrently accessible mysql user with changing permissions

Tags: php, mysql, privileges

I am working on a system to book school computer rooms using php and mysql, where there will be multiple users representing each teacher that needs to be able to book a room.

My issue is that I wish to make it possible for each user to edit their own bookings and account settings (e.g. password) without it being possible to also modify data for other users. I can quite easily implement this in the php code by modifying the queries, but I don't know how I would enforce this in mysql itself.

I have read that you cannot set mysql privileges on a per-row basis, the furthest you can go is per column, so setting multiple mysql users corresponding to each teacher which can only access bookings with their user id is impossible, if my understanding is correct. I also think this to be a bad solution even if it is possible, because it creates many unnecessary mysql users with basically the same privileges, So my question is:

Can I make a *single* mysql user that can only ever modify the currently logged-in user's data that is *also* concurrently accessible by other users with the permissions being relative to that user?

Or, is it even necessary as a security measure to do this, considering users are only meant to be able to access the database through the web interface and the mysql users are @localhost only?

Comment: IMHO, row level permissions should be implemented by your business logic. Most PHP/MySQL applications use a single database user and implement their own authorization layer.

Comment: @ZombieHunter ok, so instead should I just make a single user with enough permissions to cover all user and admin functionality, with the php being set up to force only certain queries which the current user has access to?

Comment: Basically yes. Maybe its worth creating two MySQL users, one used for the back-end or administrative tasks (that might need DDL rights) and one for the front-end used by regular site visitors (that has only DML rights). The actual site users are users stored in a [user]/[account] table. Every site object is assigned to a owner that has the appropriate permissions to modify the object.

Comment: @ZombieHunter ok well none of the admins should require DDL rights, so I'll just make one DML-only user that the application uses and add a DDL user if the need arises. Thanks for the help I think I can move on and get it working now. By the way how can I mark this as solved?

Comment: You can only mark a question as solved if there is an answer, but I don't think mine is detailed enough to qualify as an answer.